# Regex selecting separate numbers

Tags: java, regex

How it is possible to select numbers which are seperater from characters for example in such cases:

```
1221 ; =123 ; >156 ; != 56
```

and ignore in shuch ases:

```
asd446 ; das64adsa ; 5465sdad ; aasd59.status
```

Comment: Have you tried `\b\d+\b`

Comment: Use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: i used but ` ssss633 ` is also selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said in the comments, you could either use word boundaries like so:

```
\b\d+\b
```

Or, in general lookarounds (negative/positive lookahead/behind).
See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sY4lZ7/1).

Just for training purpose, you could as well use the [already mentionned lookarounds](https://regex101.com/r/sY4lZ7/2):

```
(?<=^|[=>\s])\d+(?=$|[\s])
```

This says: *look for the start **or** `=`, `>` or a whitespace **behind** and make also sure that what **immediately** follows, is either the end of the string (`$`)  or a whitespace*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
((?<=;)[+\-=><! ]+\d+|^\d+)\s*(?=(?:;|$))
```

Sample input text:

```
1221 ; =123 ; >156 ; != 56
asd446 ; das64adsa ; 5465sdad ; aasd59.status
sdkd 55 2
```

After running on sample, it matches

```
1221
=123
>156
!= 56
```